# How can you find the antiderivative of absolute value of $x$?

Tags: integration, absolute-value

In high school calculus, I am in the unit on antidifferentiation and its applications. One of its applications is finding distances with a velocity function. You can use this to find both net distance and total distance. To find the total distance, you take the integral of the absolute value of velocity like this: $\int |v(t)|dt$. This is possible by taking the derivative of $v(t)$ and solving for $0$ in order to find when $v(t)$ is negative. My question though, is can you solve this as one equation — $\int|v(t)|dt$. Here is my work showing my original thought process which failed:
$v(t)=3t^2+6t-9$. Then the total distance can be represented by $\int_a^b|v(t)|dt$ where $a$ is $t_1$ and $b$ is $t_2$. In order to solve this, you will need the antiderivative of $v(t)$ which I will call $V(t)$. Then, by FTC, this becomes $V(b)- V(a)$. So in order to get $V(t)$, I started by doing u-sub making $u = 3t^2+6t-9$. The integral becomes $\int|u|dt$. In order to get $du$, I solved for $t$ getting $t=\frac{\pm\sqrt{3(u+12)}+3}{3}$. Then, $dt = \pm\frac{1}{2}(3u+36)^{-1/2}du$. Substituting $dt$ for $du$, I get $\pm\frac{1}{2}\int(3u+36)^{-1/2}|u|du$. I then tried to integrate by parts making $f(u) = (3u+36)^{-1/2}$, $g(u)=\int|u|du$ which I thought was $u^2$, then $f'(u) = (-3/2)(3u+36)^{-3/2}$ and $g'(u) = |u|$. This is where I know now that I went wrong. $\int|u|du \neq u^2$. I found this out the hard way by continuing with my working out and then finally getting an answer for $\left.V(t)\right\rvert_a^b$ that completely failed to match up with the easy way of doing this. Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do here? If so, could anybody point me in the right direction? Keep in mind, I am only in high school calculus and as a side note, if you use the integration function on Desmos, it plots the right graph which I checked by testing it with two numbers and FTC.

Comment: $\int |v(t)|dt = |v(t)| \frac{V(t)}{v(t)}$

Comment: @Quanto Why? where does this come from?

Comment: @Quanto also, this graph does not match with the graph from desmos, so when you actually put in numbers, it doesn't match

Comment: To find the *antiderivative*, do it piecewise since $|x|$ is a piecewise function. Because it is continuous, the $+C$s on both components are in fact equal. For the definite integral, just find the zeroes and integrate each piece.

Comment: You'll need to find points where the function $v(t)$ changes it's sign...and then you'll have to break the integral appropriately

Comment: Or use the $\textrm{sgn}$ function... that's what quanto has used

Comment: $$\int_0^x |x'|\mathrm dx'=\begin{cases}\int_0^x x'\mathrm dx' & x\geq 0 \\ \int_x^0 x'\mathrm dx' & x<0\end{cases}=\begin{cases} x^2/2 & x\geq 0 \\ -x^2/2 & x<0\end{cases}=x|x|.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $|v(t)|$ has no derivative at $t=1$ and $t=-3$.

That’s why you can not find a antiderivative, so using substitution does not help.

You have to integrate over the positive and negative parts of $v(t)$ separately. even for the simpler function $v(t)=|t|$.

Answer (score 2):

There exists an explicit formula for the antiderivative of function $f$ defined by $f(x)=|x|$ which is

$$F(x)=\tfrac12 x |x| +k$$

[image]

Indeed

- for $x \ge 0, |x|=x \implies F(x)=\tfrac12 x^2 +k \implies F'(x)=x=f(x)$
- for $x \le 0, |x|=-x \implies F(x)=-\tfrac12 x^2 + k \implies F'(x)=-x = f(x)$

Comment: This is correct, and suggests why Desmos can manage the problem, but it's less informative than suggesting that the OP just do the integration piecewise.